# Dynamic Class Instantiation in VB (System.Windows.Forms)

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, class, dynamic

I need a dynamic class instantiation in VB. I get a string like "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" and dynamically depending on that string set the type of my object to TextBox.

I already tried "Activator.CreateInstance(...)" and "CallByName(...)" but I wasn't able to make it work.

Anybody has an idea how this could work?

Thanks

Comment: Am I able to create it dynamically with a string when I use "Me.controls.add" ?

Comment: The argument of method Controlcollection.Controls.Add is a control, not a string. So you have to analyze the string and cast the appropriate value accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function CreateClass(ByVal className As String) As Object

    Dim asms() As Assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies

    For Each Asm As Assembly In asms
        Dim types = Asm.GetTypes

        For Each T As Type In types
            If T.Name.Equals(className, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                Return Activator.CreateInstance(T)
            End If
        Next

    Next

    Throw New Exception("Type not found")
End Function
```

Comment: It worked ;) Thank you! I only got another problem when I want to create a label an error occurs "The public member "Location" for type "label" was not found" :/

Comment: Please mark the answer as useful.
What line generates the exception?
What is the string you pass to the function?

Comment: I pass just "Label". The error always appears in the first line where I declare an attribute, for example "obj.Autosize = true". But it doesn't matter what attribute I want to declare it also appears with "obj.Location =..." and so on.

Comment: You have to add the instance of T to the controls with Me.Controls.Add(T)

Comment: Ok got it ;)    Just one more question, is there a way to do the same with properties? Like "obj.Location...", that I can dynamically create the property ".Location" or ".Size"?

Comment: The control is already instantiated with all its properties and methods. You cannot create a "property" without a control or a class

Comment: Ok but is there a way to dynamically choose a property? Like ".Location" and so on

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In the case above you add T to the control collection so you can access its .Location property with `T.Location = New point (x,y)` ...

Comment: For Example:

Dim prop As String = "Location"
[...]
T.prop = [...]

So I could possibly loop at "T" and change the property everytime by changing the parameter "prop" dynamically. The reason is because some UI Elements have additional properties like GroupBox got TabStop.

Comment: `CallByName(T, prop, CallType.Get)`  
`CallByName(T, prop, CallType.Set, new Point(x,y))`

Comment: Thanks Alessandro for your patience :) Everything worked so far :)